# Android- in quiz game generating random

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am learning android and creating a quiz game. In the game there are different level novice,Easy,medium,hard and there is part where I have to generate random arithmetic maths questions which I have managed to do which appears as some thing like this 20+7,20-3,10*2,20/2(all of them are random as in the game.)I need help to restrict the game to maximum of ten questions.

Any help would be great .thanks

Below is my code for play class.

```
  package com.example.quiz2;

 import java.util.Random;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;


public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



//gameplay elements
private int level = 0, answer = 0, operator = 0, operand1 = 0, operand2 = 0,operand3= 0, operand4 = 0,operand5 = 0, operand6 = 0;
//operator constants
private final int ADD_OPERATOR = 0, SUBTRACT_OPERATOR = 1, MULTIPLY_OPERATOR = 2,
        DIVIDE_OPERATOR = 3;
//operator text
private String[] operators = {"+", "-", "x", "/"};
//min and max for each level and operator
private int[][] levelMin = {
        {1, 13, 21,28},
        {1, 6, 12,16},
        {2, 8, 13,18},
        {2, 4, 7,12}};
private int[][] levelMax = {
        {10, 25, 45,85},
        {10, 20, 55,90},
        {5, 10, 15,25},
        {10, 50, 100,200}};
//random number generator
private Random random;
//ui elements
private TextView question, answerTxt;
private ImageView response;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    //text 
    question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    answerTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
    response = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.response);

    //hide tick cross initially
    response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    //number, enter and delete buttons 


      View btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);//finding button with id
      btn1.setOnClickListener(this);//listening for clicks
      View btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
      btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
      btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
      btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn5 = findViewById(R.id.btn5);
      btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn6 = findViewById(R.id.btn6);
      btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn7 = findViewById(R.id.btn7);
      btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn8 = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
      btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn9 = findViewById(R.id.btn9);
      btn9.setOnClickListener(this);
      View btn0 = findViewById(R.id.btn0);
      btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
      View enter = findViewById(R.id.enter);
      enter.setOnClickListener(this); 
      View del = findViewById(R.id.del);
      del.setOnClickListener(this);




    //get passed level number
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        int passedLevel = extras.getInt("level", -1);
        if(passedLevel>=0) level = passedLevel;
    }

    //initialize random
    random = new Random();
    //play
    chooseQuestion();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId()==R.id.enter){
        //enter button
        //get answer
        String answerContent = answerTxt.getText().toString();
        //check we have an answer
        if(!answerContent.endsWith("?")){
            //get number
            int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));


            //check answer
            if(enteredAnswer==answer){
                //correct

                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                //incorrect

                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            chooseQuestion();
        }
    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.del){
        //clear button
        answerTxt.setText("=");
    }
    else {
        //number button
        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //get number from tag
        int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        //either first or subsequent digit
        if(answerTxt.getText().toString().endsWith("?"))
            answerTxt.setText("= "+enteredNum);
        else
            answerTxt.append(""+enteredNum);
    }
}



//method generates questions
private void chooseQuestion(){
    //reset answer text
    answerTxt.setText("= ?");
    //choose operator
    operator = random.nextInt(operators.length);
    //choose operands
    operand1 = getOperand();
    operand2 = getOperand();
    operand3 = getOperand();
    operand4 = getOperand();
    operand5 = getOperand();



    //checks for operators
    if(operator==SUBTRACT_OPERATOR){
        //no negative answers
        while(operand2>operand1){
            operand1 = getOperand();
            operand2 = getOperand();
        }
    }
    else if(operator==DIVIDE_OPERATOR){
        //whole numbers only
        while((((double)operand1/(double)operand2)%1 > 0) 
                || (operand1==operand2)){
            operand1 = getOperand();
            operand2 = getOperand();
        }
    }

    //calculate answer
    switch(operator){
    case ADD_OPERATOR:
        answer = operand1+operand2-operand3;
        break;
    case SUBTRACT_OPERATOR:
        answer = operand1-operand2+operand3;
        break;
    case MULTIPLY_OPERATOR:
        answer = operand1*operand2;
        break;
    case DIVIDE_OPERATOR:
        answer = operand1/operand2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    //show question
    question.setText(operand1+" "+operators[operator]+" "+operand3+operators[operator]+" "+operand4);
}

//method generates operands
private int getOperand(){
    return random.nextInt(levelMax[operator][level] - levelMin[operator][level] + 1) 
            + levelMin[operator][level];
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see one question, I see at least 3. StackOverflow is for help with specific issues and questions, not a service to write your app for you.

Comment: @WoogieNoogie I now its not a service but If you can help me with 1 or last one that will be very kind of you. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.random to set the integers to random numbers by using the nextint method

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html

Comment: I am using the random function but as I need to make a tweak somewhere in code which will give 3 or 4 expression  depending on level as mentioned in questions.